# Receiving " error: ' void ' type not allowed when checking JButton status in Tic Tac Toe game

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton, actionlistener

I have 9 scenarios making a 9 conditional statement that will look to see if all the my JButton have been pressed and no winner was found, but it is giving me " error:  ' void ' type not allowed here.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class TicTacToe extends JFrame
{
private final int HEIGHT = 450;
private final int WIDTH = 500;
private static JButton [] button = new JButton[9];
private static Action [] playerTurn = new Action[9];
private static JLabel [] label;
private int player = 1;
private Font arial = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20);
private static int lockButtons = 0;


public TicTacToe ()
{
    setTitle( " tic tak tow ");
    setSize( HEIGHT, WIDTH);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);



    setLayout(new GridLayout(4,3));

    int num = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++ )
    {

        button[i] = new JButton( "B" + i + 1);
        playerTurn[i] = new Action();
        add(button[i]);
        button[i].setFont(arial);
        button[i].addActionListener(playerTurn[i]);
    }


    setVisible(true);
}

private class Action implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent playerMove)
    {
        //Get button pressed using GetSource Command
        JButton whatPlayer=(JButton)(playerMove.getSource());

            if(player == 1)
            {
                player++;
                whatPlayer.setText("player1");
                whatPlayer.setEnabled(false); 
                validate(); 
                return;
            }               
            if (player == 2)
            {
                player--;
                whatPlayer.setText("player2");
                whatPlayer.setEnabled(false);
                validate(); 
                return;
            }
    }
    public void validate()
    {
        if(button[0].getText().equals(button[1].getText()) && button[1].getText().equals(button[2].getText()))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Thank you the winner is" + button[0].getText());
            gameOver();
        }
        if(button[3].getText().equals(button[4].getText()) && button[4].getText().equals(button[5].getText()))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Thank you the winner is" + button[3].getText());
            gameOver();
        }
        if(button[6].getText().equals(button[7].getText()) && button[7].getText().equals(button[8].getText()))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Thank you the winner is" + button[6].getText());
            gameOver();
        }
        if(button[0].getText().equals(button[3].getText()) && button[3].getText().equals(button[6].getText()))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Thank you the winner is" + button[0].getText());
            gameOver();
        }
        if(button[1].getText().equals(button[4].getText()) && button[4].getText().equals(button[7].getText()))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Thank you the winner is" + button[1].getText());
            gameOver();
        }
        if(button[1].getText().equals(button[4].getText()) && button[4].getText().equals(button[7].getText()))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Thank you the winner is" + button[1].getText());
            gameOver();
        }
        if(button[2].getText().equals(button[5].getText()) && button[5].getText().equals(button[8].getText()))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Thank you the winner is" + button[2].getText());
            gameOver();
        }
        if(button[0].getText().equals(button[4].getText()) && button[4].getText().equals(button[8].getText()))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Thank you the winner is" + button[0].getText());
            gameOver();
        }
        if(button[2].getText().equals(button[4].getText()) && button[4].getText().equals(button[6].getText()))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Thank you the winner is" + button[2].getText());
            gameOver();
        }
        if ( button.length == setEnabled(false))  // this is the problem.  Don't know if I worded it correctly
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"This was a Draw");
        }

    }
    public void gameOver()
    {
        for( int x = 0; x < button.length; x++)
        {
            button[x].setEnabled(false);
        }
    }


}
public static void main(String[] arg)
{
    new TicTacToe();
}   
}
```

Comment: What do you want to test in this uncompilable line?

Comment: I am looking to test if all my Jbuttons have been pressed.  This way if all the button are pressed an there are no winners the game ended in a stale mate

Comment: OK. So you want to test that all the buttons have been pressed. If a button has been pressed, then it's disabled. So you want to test that all the buttons are disabled. Create a method for that: `boolean allButtonsDisabled()`. It should iterate through the buttons, and return false as soon as one button is still enabled. At the end, if it hasn't return false, it means that all buttons are disabled, so it should return true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

button.length will be equal to 9 since you defined an array of 9 elements

```
private static JButton [] button = new JButton[9];
```

How can you do this `if ( button.length == setEnabled(false))` comparision in if loop,
`setEnabled(false)` is going to disable the JFrame and the return type is void,here you are comparing the int with void that's why the error is thrown at the compile time.

```
int i;

for(i=0;i<button.length;i++){
     if(b[i].isEnabled()){
     break;
     }
}

if(i==button.length){
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"This was a Draw");
}
```

Comment: Ok after reading Java Doc. I see that I could use the isEnables function.  however it still gives me the same error? should I make a Boolean variable??

Comment: What logic you need to write in this if statement?

Comment: I want something like this if( ( !button.isEnabled()) , then ir is a draw.  However would this work better in a while loop?

Comment: I edited my post check that.If all the buttons are disabled then show draw.